# Conditions on variance for a probability distribution to have a specific third moment.

Tags: probability

Take a random variable $X$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}$, which wlog has expectation zero, and fix its variance. What are the possible third moments, $\mathbb{E}(X^3)$, it can have?

Is the only condition that the variance be non-zero, and then any $\mathbb{E}(X^3)$ is possible?

I was actually interested in the case where $X$ takes values in $\mathbb{R^3}$, and you fix the covariance $\mathbb{E}(X_i X_j)$, and ask what are the possible values of the vector $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_i X_j)$ (summation notation), but I can probably work this out from an answer to the above case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no condition on $E(X^3)$ given $E X = 0$ and $E X^2$ fixed.

Fix a parameter $r > 0$ and define $X$ via $$P(X = r) = \frac{1}{r^2 + 1},\quad P(X = -1/r) = \frac{r^2}{r^2 + 1}\,.$$

Note that:

1. $E[X] = 0$
2. $\mathrm{Var}[X] = E[X^2] = 1$.
3. $E[X^3] = \frac{1}{r^2+1}\left(r^3 - 1/r\right)$.

As $r$ varies in $(0,\infty)$ note that $E[X^3]$ varies over all of $\mathbb{R}$.